# How to use StorageItem to save vsto add-in specific data

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, msdn

I am developing a VSTO add-in for Outlook in C#. I would want to be able to save some add-in specific data, which is a complex user defined type. I have gone through the MSDN documentaion of [StorageItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.storageitem.aspx) API, but doesn't help much. Is using the StorageItem the right approach? Any code samples would help.

Comment: What code exactly did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Because solution storage is created as hidden items in a folder, you can only store solution data if the store provider supports hidden items and the client has rights to write to that folder.

```
private string GetWorkHoursXML()
{
   try
   {
        Outlook.StorageItem storage =
        Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
        Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).GetStorage(
        "IPM.Configuration.WorkHours",
        Outlook.OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass);
        Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = storage.PropertyAccessor;
        // PropertyAccessor will return a byte array for this property
        byte[] rawXmlBytes = (byte[])pa.GetProperty(
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C080102");
        // Use Encoding to convert the array to a string
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rawXmlBytes);
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
 }
```

See [How to: Store Solution-Specific Data as a Hidden Message in a Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623414(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Still doesn't help. Its the same as MSDN provides. Can you provide some code sample to save my data in the storage and how to retrieve it? And your example shows only to retrieve string. But I want to be able to store and retrieve complex user defined datatypes and also retrieve them back.